# Backbone: using "model.models"

Tags: backbone.js

I'm reading a Backbone tutorial http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/ on building a wine cellar application. The author of the tutorial doesn't explain one point clearly and I can't figure it out from the documentation. Namely, the use of `this.model.models`, which you see in the render function view below

```
window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:'ul',

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function (wine) {
            $(this.el).append(new WineListItemView({model:wine}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }

});
```

The model for this view is actually a collection

```
list:function () {
        this.wineList = new WineCollection();
        this.wineListView = new WineListView({model:this.wineList});
```

And the collection declares the Wine as its model

```
window.WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Wine,
    url:"../api/wines"
});
```

So, when WineListView is instantiated, it's `this.model` is actually the Wine List Collection. And, from the documentation, `models` provides access to an array of models inside a collection

```
modelscollection.models 
Raw access to the JavaScript array of models inside of the collection. Usually you'll want to use get, at, or the Underscore methods to access model objects, but occasionally a direct reference to the array is desired.
```

So if `this.model` is already the collection of wines (due to the collection being declared as the model in the view), why is it necessary to do `this.model.models`? to essentially get the collection again?

Comment: Hmmm. Backbone views have a `collection` property that should be used instead of `model` when the view is viewing a collection rather than a single object. [One of the comments](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/#comment-27575) does note this problem but there was no response from the tutorial's author. [Derick Bailey's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/93448/derick-bailey) blog postings might be a better place to learn this stuff.

Comment: @muistooshort ok thanks, i didn't see that comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is essentially a stylistic choice. The code

```
_.each(this.model.models, function (wine) {
    $(this.el).append(...);
}, this);
```

simply iterates through the models in the collection, and should be equivalent to:

```
this.model.each(function (wine) {
    $(this.el).append(...);
}, this);
```

I would have thought the second version was easier to read, but each to his/her own...

Comment: I wonder if the tutorial author is confusing himself by using the view's `model` property to hold a collection rather than using `collection` to hold the collection.

Comment: @muistooshort so when the author did view, he could have done the following?    new View(collection: wine)

Comment: @Michael: Yes, that would have been a better choice, the view constructor handles [`collection` specially just like `model`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor). Then you'd say `this.collection.each(function(wine) { ... })`; collections have [some Underscore methods](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) already mixed in so there's no need to say `_(this.collection).each(...)` or `_.each(this.collection, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, to get it to work I had to do the following :

```
    _.each(this.model.models, function (foto) {
        console.log(foto.attributes);
        $(this.el).append(new App.view.foto.foto({model:foto.attributes}).render().el);
    }, this);
```

Not sure why accesing .attributes does the trick, am I missing any convertion?

I am bootstrapping from the DB the following JSON string:

```
[{
    "fid": 1,
    "imagen": "sample_colors.jpg",
    "width": "110",
    "height": "110",
    "dimension_id": 1,
    "seccion_id": 1,
    "estado": 0,
    "fecha": {
        "date": "2012-06-27 23:02:27",
        "timezone_type": 2,
        "timezone": "PDT"
    }
}, {
    "fid": 2,
    "imagen": "sample_colors.jpg",
    "width": "110",
    "height": "110",
    "dimension_id": 1,
    "seccion_id": 1,
    "estado": 1,
    "fecha": {
        "date": "2012-06-27 12:03:02",
        "timezone_type": 2,
        "timezone": "PDT"
    }
}, {
    "fid": 3,
    "imagen": "sample_colors.jpg",
    "width": "110",
    "height": "110",
    "dimension_id": 1,
    "seccion_id": 1,
    "estado": 2,
    "fecha": {
        "date": "2012-06-27 12:03:20",
        "timezone_type": 2,
        "timezone": "PDT"
    }
}]
```